# Why does a function have the word constant at the end even though it does change a variable

Tags: c++

My understanding of the keyword 'const' is that it says to the compiler, that the function will not modify any of the variables but in the following example it changes `b.d`. why?

```
myClass operator + (myClass b) const { b.d += d; return b; }
```

Comment: Look back at what it does more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` function can't modify variables of `this`(the calling object) (if variable is not `mutable`). in example `this` is not modified. so, it's correct.

variable `b` is another object of class `myClass`.

```
myClass operator + (myClass b) const
```

is

```
myClass operator + (const myClass* this, myClass b)
```

better to use `member-operator +=` and `not member operator +`, for example

```
myClass& myClass::operator += (const myClass& rhs)
{
    d += rhs.d;
    return *this;
}

myClass operator + (const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs)
{
   myClass tmp(lhs);
   tmp += rhs;
   return tmp;
}
```

Comment: You have to understand that `b` object itself isn't part of `this`. Members of the object that invoked the call only can't be modified.

Comment: Better to pass in lhs by value and just return `lhs += rhs` imo.

Comment: @chris mb. but i prefer this signature.

Comment: @ForEveR: is symmetry worth a loss of efficiency ;) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. copy will be in both cases (not taking into account compiler optimization).

Comment: @ForEveR: With copy elision and move constructors, the "not taking into account compiler optimization" statement is quite naive though...